# Why can't I find the GetEnumerator() method on the IList type through reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, ilist

This code is of course valid. IList by definition, has a GetEnumerator() method.

```
System.Collections.IList list = new List<string>();
System.Collections.IEnumerator ienum = list.GetEnumerator();
```

However none of the following are able to find a member of the IList type with the name GetEnumerator.

```
Type iListType= typeof(System.Collections.IList);
var member = iListType.GetMember("GetEnumerator");
var members = iListType.GetMembers().Where(x => x.Name == "GetEnumerator");
var method = iListType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
var methods = iListType.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "GetEnumerator");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find `GetEnumerator` on the `IList` type, because the `IList` type does not declare `GetEnumerator`. `IList` extends `IEnumerable` which declares it. So you need to change your code to look for `GetEnumerator` on the `IEnumerable` type.

```
Type type = typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable);
var member = type.GetMember("GetEnumerator");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a member of `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you cannot look up for members for interfaces that an interface has implemented. But to workaround this use:

```
var member = iListType.GetInterfaces().Union(new Type[] { iListType }).SelectMany(t => t.GetMember("GetEnumerator"));
```

You code works with a class type but not an interface type. That is strange. I checked it with `System.Collections.ArrayList` and it returned one method.

Comment: I know that. But, I am not sure why we don't have an easy (may be using `BindingFlags`) way to look for methods defined in base interface types.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to set `BindingFlags` in this case.

Try This...

```
MemberInfo[] member = iListType.GetMember("GetEnumerator", BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: Wrong. The default value for the `BindingFlags` parameter is `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance` which includes `BindingFlags.Public`.